# What is Ziproxy and what can be used for?

Tags: caching, http-proxy

simply I want to know what is Ziproxy and what is it for? I noticed that some and very limited articles talk about it on the internet. I thought it is an outdated cache proxy, yet no enough information about.

I would appreciate it if someone can explain what is it and what can be used for?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ziproxy is a proxy, but it does not do any caching. What it does is reducing data usage for clients connected to it. The data usage is reduced by applying additional compression on images and text data.
Images will be compressed with JPEG or JPEG2000 with a higher compression ration as usual. Of course you will notice a difference in quallity but you will save a lot of traffic. You can also gain additional savings by compressing all text based content like HTML or CSS and Java Script by using GZIP compression.
Usually you might want to install it on your server at home that has a fast network connection. When using mobile devices like Smartphones or Tablets you can do a VPN connection to your home network to access your Zimproxy proxy to save data usage.

Client (e.g. phone) → Internet / VPN → Ziproxy → Internet → Website

You might combine Ziproxy with a caching proxy like Squid or tinyproxy. There are some thoughts about where to place Ziproxy ... before or after a caching proxy. I would personally put it before the cache (client → caching proxy → Ziproxy → Internet).
This would mean that an image requested by the client might have been compressed already by Ziproxy.